# EF Core stored where Func does not generate SQL where clause

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make an EF generic repository, but when pass as parameter to a method a variable with Func where, does not generate the where clause.

Examble:

This generate SQL where clause

```
 var data = dbSet.Where((m => (m.Field != null && m.Field.Contains(searchValue))));
```

This not:

```
var whereClause = (m => (m.Field != null && m.Field.Contains(searchValue)));
var data = dbSet.Where(whereClause);
```

Comment: `var whereClause = ...` does not compile. Anyway, make sure to use `Expression<Func<...>>` parameters like `Queryable` methods instead of `Func<…>` which match `Enumerable` methods, thus won't be translated to SQL and will be executed in-memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ivan Stoev told us, this not compile : `var whereClause = ...`

but you can do something like this :

```
var data = FindEntity((m => (m.Field != null && m.Field.Contains(searchValue))));
//T is your dbSet Data type
private IEnumerable<T> FindEntity(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereClause)
{
    return dbset.Where(whereClause)
        .AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, i used to use Func instead of Expression<Func